# Combine several variables in url

Tags: url, get

I like to combine these two url-variables.  I have quite long code, may I shorten it:

```
// first statement
if (!empty($_GET["urlparameter1"]))
{$_SESSION["urlparameter1"] = $_GET["urlparameter1"];}
$urlparameter1= $_SESSION["urlparameter1"];

// combine this with first statement
if (!empty($_GET["urlparameter2"]))
{$_SESSION["urlparameter2"] = $_GET["urlparameter2"];}
$urlparameter1= $_SESSION["urlparameter2"];
```

how to I transfer 2 or more  get-variables in url?

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and a desired output?

Comment: What do you mean by *combine*?

Comment: I use the urlparameter in an sql-statement like: SELECT * FROM x where x = $urlparameter1 - this also works. But I need a 2nd.

Comment: The first statement works, I need a second parameter

Comment: I like to add a second parameter, but do not know how, I think something like: if (!empty($_GET["urlparameter1,urlparameter2,"]))
{$_SESSION["urlparameter1"] = $_GET["urlparameter1, urlparameter2"];}
$urlparameter1, $urlparameter2= $_SESSION["urlparameter1", "urlparameter2"];

Comment: how to I transfer 2 or more get-variables in url?

Comment: I found the solution, its just
    $urlparameter1 = $_GET["urlparameter1"];
    $urlparameter2 = $_GET["urlparameter2"];

Answer (score -1):

To combine all parameters in one variable I just use

$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']

This works. Found via http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.server.php :-)